# Modifying instance variables from inner function in a prototype method

Tags: javascript, oop, scope

I'm attempting to model the data in my database as "classes" in server-side JavaScript (Node).
For the moment, I'm simply using the traditional constructor pattern with prototype methods where appropriate and exposing the constructor function as the entire `module.exports`. The fact that this is server side is unimportant to the core of the question, but I figured I'd provide it as reference.

The problem area of code looks like this:

```
User.prototype.populate = function() {  
    var that = this;    
    db.collection("Users").findOne({email : that.email}, function(err, doc){
        if(!err) {
            that.firstName  = doc.firstName;
            that.lastName   = doc.lastName;
            that.password   = doc.password;
        }
        console.log(that); //expected result
    });
   console.log(that); //maintains initial values
};
```

Whenever I call this function, changes to the object do not persist once the `findOne()` has completed. I realize that the scope of `this` changes to the global object with new function scopes, so I maintained its reference as `that`. If `console.log(that)` from within the anonymous function, the data shows up in the properties of it as expected. However, if I log `that` once the function has finished, it maintains the state it had at the beginning of the function.

What's going on here and how I can I change instance variables as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"However, if I log that once the function has finished, ..."*

By this I assume you're doing something like this...

```
var user = new User

user.populate();

console.log(user);
```

If so, the `console.log` will run long before the *asynchronous* callback to `.findOne()` has been invoked.

Any code that relies on the response to `findOne` needs to be invoked inside the callback.

---

***EDIT:*** Your update is a little different from my example above, but the reason is the same.

The entire reason for passing a callback to the `findOne` method is that it performs an *asynchronous* activity. If it didn't, there's be no reason for the callback. You'd just place the inner code directly after the call to `findOne`, as you did with the `console.log()`.

But because it's *asynchronous*, the subsequent code doesn't wait to execute. That's why you're getting the unpopulated object in the console.

If you add a label to each `console.log()`, you'll see that they execute out of order.

---

```
var that = this;    
db.collection("Users").findOne({email : that.email}, function(err, doc){
    if(!err) {
        that.firstName  = doc.firstName;
        that.lastName   = doc.lastName;
        that.password   = doc.password;
    }
    console.log("inside the callback", that); // this happens Last!!!
});

console.log("outside the callback", that); // this happens First!!!
```

So it becomes clear once you observer the order of the `console.log` calls that the empty one is happening before the one inside the callback.

---

***EDIT:*** You can also have your `.populate()` method receive a callback that is invoked inside the `.findOne` callback.

```
User.prototype.createNickName = function () {
    this.nickname = this.firstName.slice(0,3) + '_' + this.lastName.slice(0,3);
};

    // >>>------------------------------v----receive a function argument...
User.prototype.populate = function(callback_func) {  
    var that = this;    
    db.collection("Users").findOne({email : that.email}, function(err, doc){
        if(!err) {
            that.firstName  = doc.firstName;
            that.lastName   = doc.lastName;
            that.password   = doc.password;
        }

          // all users will have the "createNickName()" method invoked
        that.createNickName();

          // ...and invoke it in the callback.
        callback_func.call(that);

          // By using .call(), I'm setting the "this" value
          //    of callback_func to whatever is passed as the first argument
    });
};
```

---

```
   // this user wants to log the firstName property in all caps
var user1 = new User;

user1.populate(function() {
    console.log(this.firstName.toUpperCase());
});


   // this user wants to log the the whole name
var user2 = new User;

user2.populate(function() {
    console.log(this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName);
});


   // this user wants to verify that the password is sufficiently secure
var user3 = new User;

user3.populate(function() {
    console.log(verify_password(this.password));
});
```

Comment: That's correct. Though this happens both with an external call logging user.populate() as well as within the populate() method itself (but outside the scope of findOne()). I've updated the post to reflect what I meant.

Comment: @user574930: Refresh your browser. I already updated my answer.

Comment: With this knowledge, then, how would I be able to achieve the effect I'm looking for where I can simply call the populate() method and know the object's properties will get updated?

Comment: By passing more callbacks - if you want to, say, render a page when the properties are updated, put that into a function and pass it down the chain and call it inside the db.collection callback.

Comment: @DuxPrime: Well, you need to think of your flow of code as being diverted into the callback you passed to `findOne`. So it's in there that you'll continue your coding. Also, it's important to remember that functions *(and therefore functionality)* can be passed like any other data.

Comment: ...Exactly. You can have your `.populate()` function receive a function that you pass it when you call it. Then you can invoke that function inside the `findOne` callback.

Comment: @DuxPrime: I updated again. I may have misunderstood your last comment. You can certainly call another function, or call a function on the `prototype` of your `User` object as well. My latest example reflects all 3 possibilities.

Comment: I think I understand why this is happening in terms of the functions not being linear, but it seems silly to pass a function with a reference to the User to a method that is _attached_ to the user. I guess I was hoping I could keep everything encapsulated since the User object knows its own data.

Comment: @DuxPrime: Yeah, there are many ways to do it. All depends on what's needed. Since you're dealing with an object with prototyped methods, then it would make sense that one of those methods would be what you would call. Then again, if you have some general use functions, you can pass them as an argument.

Comment: @DuxPrime: Tell you what... I'm going to update my last example to give a better illustration of why you might pass a function. Basically, let's say that different `User` objects will want to do different things when the `.populate()` is complete. Instead of hard-coding `.populate()` with all the different possibilities, you'd just have each `user` object pass a callback. You'll see that I use `.call()` to invoke the function so I can set the `this` value of your callback to the same `user` object.